# Find a polynomial of the form $F(x,y,z)$ of degree $3$ such that $F(a,b,c) = 0 \pmod{5}$ iff $a,b,c= 0 \pmod{5}$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

I am trying to solve this question to study for my Number Theory final exam

QUESTION: Find a polynomial of the form  $F(x,y,z)$ of degree 3 such that $F(a,b,c) \equiv  0 \pmod{5}$ iff  $a,b,c \equiv 0\pmod{5}$

My attempt:
"$\longrightarrow$"
Let $f=x + y+ z$, Then take $f(a,b,c)= a + b + c \equiv 0\pmod{5} $ .

Then we know that $5| a + b + c$, thus the polynomial must be re-written as $5a + 5b + 5c$. Hence, when taken modulo 5, $a,b,c \equiv 0\pmod{5}$

PD: I Don't seem to understand how to prove the converse, I know Hensel's lemma, but not too sure how to apply it I still need to find the degree 3 polynomial.... Please help, I am a beginner, and I'm still learning.

UPDATE PLEASE READ: I had an Idea, please tell me what you guys think.

Let $f(x,y,z)=x^3 + y^3 + z^3$

So, suppose that $a,b,c \equiv 0$ mod 5. Then we can rewrite $a,b,c$ as $5k,5t,5m$. Then, when we plug these in the original equation, we will get:
$f(5k,5t,5m)=125k + 125t + 125m$ which is $\equiv 0 $ mod 5.

Then, Supp. that $f(a,b,c) \equiv 0 $ mod 5. Then we can write $a^3 = 5t+ (-b^3 - c^3)$. But, if we rewrite b , and c in the same way, we will get that all contain a $5*$(some variable). Thus, in $a^3 = 5t + (-b^3 -c^3)$ we are able to factor out  a 5, therefore we will get that $a^3 = 5*(something)$ which implies $a \equiv 0$ mod 5 . Do the same for b and c....

What do you guys think? Anything helps. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well I suppose the question to ask is what have you learned i.e., what level was this course at?

Comment: For *just two* variables $a$ and $b$, and degree-$2$ it's easier: $F(a,b)=a^2+2b^2$ would do in that case.

Comment: Thanks... I need to find the polynomial....

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a [non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content](/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that this is just a hint. First, the natural environment for this is $\Bbb F_5=\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$. You’re looking for a cubic form in three variables with no non-trivial zeros in $\Bbb F_5$.

Consider the (unique) cubic extension $k$ of your base field, find an explicit description of it for your computations. Now let $\{1=b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ be an $\Bbb F_5$-basis of $k$, and look at a general element $g=A+Bb_2+Cb_3$. Then, describe the (field-theoretic) Norm $\mathbf N^k_{\Bbb F_5}(g)$ of $g$, which you can describe as the product of $g$ with its two conjugates (*), or as the constant term of the $\Bbb F_5$-minimal polynomial of $g$. You’ll get a cubic form in the variables $A,B,C$. Now it’s a fact about the Norm that  it’s nonzero for nonzero arguments, that is, elements of $k^\times$. And there you are.

(*) You treat $A,B,C$ here as elements of the base field $\Bbb F_5$, so not affected by elements of the Galois group.

Comment: Thank you!. Is there a different way??? I don't know about Galois Group...

Comment: This does need to be elaborated on, please, it really does not answer the question as is...

Comment: Do you want me to do the answer out, @Mike ? I can, and it won’t take very long, but it will deprive the OP of all fun merely to read what I’ve written.

Comment: As the OP themself mentioned, they didn't study Galois groups....I think an elementary solution is what is called for here

Comment: ...or a more elementary solution, if you would, Sir....